# No sound after resume on 20.04

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, resume

My laptop **HP ZBook Fury 15 G7 Mobile Workstation** has the problem that there's no sound after I suspend and resume it. The only solution I found so far is reboot.
I have 2 cards on my laptop, one is `HDA Nvidia` controlled by `snd_hda_intel` driver and the other is `sof-hda-dsp` controlled by `snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp` driver. Not sure about Nvidia card - didn't use it so far, but the problem is with the latter, which is my "main" sound card labeled `Realtek ALC285`. Sound works fine until I suspend and resume the laptop and nothing in the log seem to point to the cause of the problem...

logs from `alsa-info` when sound is working:
https://pastebin.com/0CuJWiG1

When it's not working (after resume):
https://pastebin.com/CGD2GDGb

the logs are from when I added the following to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd slots=snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
options snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=1
```

Think I tried most solutions I could find on the net. Re-inserting `snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp` hangs forever. I also had this problem with `pulseaudio` being started by `gdm`, I stopped it but it didn't make any difference so not sure how important it is.

Another strange thing is that although the sound card is reported as 2 channel, it seems like the `front-left` channel is the only one that works, but all speakers are playing as if it was one giant mono speaker only. Playing anything on `front-right` or changing balance results in no sound.

Would be grateful for any help, it's really hard to work if I have to restart the laptop each time I suspend it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating to 5.11-rc7 kernel. This required a manual patch of nvidia-460 driver which was incompatible with this kernel.